# Pending transaction xxx

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Please have sent my bitcoin from block chain wallet to localbitcoin wallet and keep telling me unconfirmed transaction and pending Xx please what can I do to get my bitcoin back.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a spam attack: https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions

Your transaction is likely to get confirmed If you paid enough fees but It will take time. Try to send it to ViaBTC accelerator and see how things goes.